# Perform an action when the fragment has correctly finished loading

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'd like to know when a fragment has correctly finished loading, and nexr perform an action. I don't know how can I do this!

Thanks.

Comment: Is this something you want to execute once for the fragment? Or every time the fragment comes into view? You will want to find the correct override according to the fragment lifecycle documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Because when i click on an element in a listview, with the sliding menu library, it's lagging.. so i've got the idea to perform the change when the fragment it's completely loading! I don't know if you got me! Thanks.

Comment: Nobody can answer the question?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say why things are lagging without seeing some code. But to answer your question onStart is what you want (I think). Documentation says that onStart is "Called when the Fragment is visible to the user. This is generally tied to Activity.onStart of the containing Activity's lifecycle."

Comment: Did you find a solution? If any of the answers below were helpful please accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the action in the Fragment's `onStart` or `onResume`.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     //perform action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean when you say "has correctly finished loading"? Are you doing some kind of long running task in your fragment or do you simply want to know when the fragment has gone through it's standard [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle)?

If it's simply a matter of knowing when the setup is done you should as was posted in another answer override [onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStart%28%29)

Comment: When i click on an element in a listview, with the sliding menu library, it's lagging.. so i've got the idea to perform the change when the fragment it's completely loading! I don't know if you got me! Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's hard to say why things are lagging without seeing some code. But to answer your question onStart is what you want (I think). Documentation says that onStart is "Called when the Fragment is visible to the user. This is generally tied to Activity.onStart of the containing Activity's lifecycle."

Answer (score -1):

You can call the api

```
if(fragment.isAdded()) {

}
```

to check if the fragment has been added to current activity.